# How to get each StateName TotalPopulation @2009

Tags: sql-server

Stateid StateName   Year  Population

1    andhra     2008    25000

2   andhra  2009    10000

3   ap  2008    15000

2   ap  2009    20000

How to get each StateName   TotalPopulation @2009

Comment: Is this your Homework?

Comment: Don't say like that i am trainer  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3046513/ronondex

Comment: Try to find your soln from `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546166.aspx`

Comment: You can split a string by its spaces using `inputString.Split(new [] {' '});` That is a really basic operation. Sorry but I find it hard to believe that you are a trainer when you ask such simple stuff.

Comment: i need without Linq concept :amit-agrawal

Comment: @user3257223 this **IS WIHTOUT** Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was, i broke the string into an array using the split function. Then looped through each of the element and checked whether that element has been parsed or not. If yes, the add the count by 1 else add the element to the dictionary.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputString = "I love red color. He loves red color. She love red kit.";
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            var arr = inputString.Split(' ','.',',');
            foreach (string s in arr)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(s))
                    dict[s] += 1;
                else
                    dict.Add(s, 1);
            }

            foreach (var item in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "- " + item.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much it is working fine.http://stackoverflow.com/users/2502800/ashish-charan

Comment: You should do Trim: otherwise "color." will be count as a word; the other option is to split on ' ', '.', ';' etc.

Answer (score 1):

without using the Linq, here a solution

```
Dictionary<string,int> data=new Dictionary<string,int>(); // to store the words and count
string inputString = "I love red color. He loves red color. She love red kit.";
var details=inputString.Split(' '); // split the string you have on space, u can exclude the non alphabet characters
foreach(var detail in details)
{
    // based on Ron comment you should trim the empty detail in case you have multi space in the string
    if(!string.IsNullOfEmpty(detail) && data.ContainsKey(detail))
         data[detail].Value++;
    else
        data.Add(detail,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
string inputString = "I love red color. He loves red color. She love red kit.";            Dictionary<string, int> wordcount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var words = inputString.Split(' ');
foreach (var word in words)
{
   if (!wordcount.ContainsKey(word))
        wordcount.Add(word, words.Count(p => p == word));
}
```

wordcount will have the output you are looking for. Note that it will have all entries for all words, so if you want for only a subset, then alter it to lookup against a master list.

Answer (score -2):

Check the link given bellow.

> [Count Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546166.aspx)

This example shows how to use a LINQ query to count the occurrences of a specified word in a string. Note that to perform the count, first the Split method is called to create an array of words. There is a performance cost to the Split method. If the only operation on the string is to count the words, you should consider using the Matches or IndexOf methods instead. However, if performance is not a critical issue, or you have already split the sentence in order to perform other types of queries over it, then it makes sense to use LINQ to count the words or phrases as well.

```
class CountWords
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = @"Historically, the world of data and the world of objects" +
          @" have not been well integrated. Programmers work in C# or Visual Basic" +
          @" and also in SQL or XQuery. On the one side are concepts such as classes," +
          @" objects, fields, inheritance, and .NET Framework APIs. On the other side" +
          @" are tables, columns, rows, nodes, and separate languages for dealing with" +
          @" them. Data types often require translation between the two worlds; there are" +
          @" different standard functions. Because the object world has no notion of query, a" +
          @" query can only be represented as a string without compile-time type checking or" +
          @" IntelliSense support in the IDE. Transferring data from SQL tables or XML trees to" +
          @" objects in memory is often tedious and error-prone.";

        string searchTerm = "data";

        //Convert the string into an array of words 
        string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Create and execute the query. It executes immediately  
        // because a singleton value is produced. 
        // Use ToLowerInvariant to match "data" and "Data"  
        var matchQuery = from word in source
                         where word.ToLowerInvariant() == searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
                         select word;

        // Count the matches. 
        int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences(s) of the search term \"{1}\" were found.", wordCount, searchTerm);

        // Keep console window open in debug mode
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/* Output:
   3 occurrences(s) of the search term "data" were found.
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer. Answers with just a link in it are considered invalid on SO. You should "quote" the relevant pieces from your link in your answer and use the link just as a resource.

Comment: please check updated answer and Please Upvote and accept as a answer

Comment: @SagarModi You can't just ask to upvote your question. They will upvote when they think your answer deserves it. Also your code you posted here does not use the input provided by the OP, furthermore you are outputting something different as the OP asked for.

Comment: OP requested an answer that does not use Linq.